# Need clarification concerning Windows Azure

Tags: silverlight, azure

I basically need some confirmation and clarification concerning Windows Azure with respect to a Silverlight application using RIA Services.

In a normal Silverlight app that uses RIA services you have 2 projects:

- App
- App.Web

... where App is the default client-side Silverlight and app.web is the server-side code where your RIA services go.

If you create a Windows Azure app and add a WCF Web Services Role, you get:

- App (Azure project)
- App.Services (WCF Services project)

In App.Services, you add your RIA DomainService(s). You would then add another project to this solution that would be the client-side Silverlight that accesses the RIA Services in the App.Services project.

You then can add the entity model to the App.Services or another project that is referenced by App.Services (if that division is required for unit testing etc.) and connect that entity model to either a SQLServer db or a SQLAzure instance.

Is this correct?

If not, what is the general 'layout' for building an application with the following tiers:

- UI (Silverlight 4)
- Services (RIA Services)
- Entity/Domain (EF 4)
- Data (SQL Server)

Comment: You should really edit your question again and place your findings in an answer.  That will make it easier for others to see there IS an answer to your question.

Comment: PS.  Thanks for documenting this for us.  +1.

Comment: @Walter - Is it okay for someone else to edit this and move the answer to the answer section?

Comment: Last chance to edit this question and place the answer as an answer.  Otherwise one of us will edit it and your name will not be associated with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Moved the answer from the "Question" section to the "Answers" section:**

Upon further investigation and a test deployment, it seems to work like so:

1. Create the Azure app (creates App project)
2. Create the Web service role named App.Services (creates App.Services project)
3. Create a Silverlight application, have it host in the existing App.Services
4. Create the domain layer project (App.Domain) and add the reference to App.Services
5. (In my case) create App.Tests project for unit/integration testing

Then publish via right-click menu on App project. I created the package and manually uploaded via the Azure account site. The project is listed as 'Busy' in the Azure project, and is unavailable, but everything seemed to work fine.